# jquery trigger and on looping forever

Tags: jquery, triggers, event-handling

I have an event i want to trigger each time a node is added to my dom. The event is called qt_nodeAdded

I attach a listener for this and only want it to be called when it is triggered on the div with id myID

```
$("body").on("qt_nodeAdded", "#myID", function() {
  ...
  $("#otherID").trigger("qt_nodeAdded");
  ...
});
```

in my html #otherID is wrapped inside #myID.

How can i get it to not trigger for #otherID ?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eNWZ2/

Comment: your question is not clear as to what you exactly want.. please provide more info

Comment: It is working correctly. what are you trying to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of event bubbling, one way to handle is to stop event propagation... jQuery handles this in a particular way for delegated events.

```
$("body").on("qt_nodeAdded", "#otherID", function (event, data) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5wCfd/)

Comment: Ok, so if i dont add a listener for #otherid i cant filter it and should do if(node.is("#myID") {...} in the handler?

Comment: @ArunPJohny That is what i did, but the other way around, only do my stuff if the node is #myID. Thanks for the help :)